# Loading multiple workbooks into excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

As you can see from the code, I am trying to load a single workbook into excel. Is there any way for me to select multiple workbook and upload them in one go instead of reopening the file dialogue again and again?

```
Private Sub OpenFileDialogue()
strCancel = "N"
strWorkbookNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (FileFilter:=strFilt, _
     FilterIndex:=intFilterIndex, _
     Title:=strDialogueFileTitle)
Workbooks.Open strWorkbookNameAndPath
End Sub


Public strDialogueFileTitle As String
Public strFilt As String
Public intFilterIndex As Integer
Public strCancel As String
Public strWorkbookNameAndPath As String
Public strWorkbookName As String
Public strWorksheetName As String

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wkbMasterWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wksMasterWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim wkbImportedWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wksImportedWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim rngImportCopyRange As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wkbMasterWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set wksMasterWorksheet = Sheets("Sheet1")


strFilt = "Excel Files (*.xls),*.xls," & _
          "CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv,"

intFilterIndex = 1
strDialogueFileTitle = "Select The Workbook You Want To Import"

Call OpenFileDialogue

If strCancel = "Y" Then
    MsgBox ("An Open Error Occurred Importing Your File Selection")
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wkbImportedWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksImportedWorksheet = wkbImportedWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set rngImportCopyRange = Range(wksImportedWorksheet.Cells(1, 1), Cells(250, 1)).EntireRow
rngImportCopyRange.Copy
wksMasterWorksheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
wkbMasterWorkbook.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wkbImportedWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

wksMasterWorksheet.Activate
wksMasterWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
Private Sub OpenFileDialogue()
Dim strWorkbookNameAndPath
Dim fileArraySize, i as Long

strCancel = "N"
strWorkbookNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(FileFilter:=strFilt, _
 FilterIndex:=intFilterIndex, _
 Title:=strDialogueFileTitle, _
 MultiSelect:=True)'add this line which will let you select all the files

 'your variable now contains array of filenames
 fileArraySize = Ubound(strWorkbookNameAndPath, 1) 'count how many files

 'loop and open the files
 For i = 1 to fileArraySize
     Workbooks.Open strWorkbookNameAndPath(i)
 Next i
```

**Edit1:**

```
Option Explicit
Public strDialogueFileTitle As String
Public strFilt As String
Public intFilterIndex As Integer
Public strCancel As String
Public strWorkbookNameAndPath As String
Public strWorkbookName As String
Public strWorksheetName As String

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wkbMasterWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wksMasterWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim wkbImportedWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wksImportedWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim rngImportCopyRange As Range

'added this to enhance performance and eliminate alert when you close an opened file.
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

On Error Goto errhandler 'added this just in case something came up so you won't be stuck

Set wkbMasterWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set wksMasterWorksheet = wkbMasterWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

strFilt = "Excel Files (*.xls),*.xls," & _
      "CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv,"
intFilterIndex = 1
strDialogueFileTitle = "Select The Workbook You Want To Import"
strCancel = "N"

If strCancel = "N" Then

Dim strWorkbookNameAndPath
Dim fileArraySize, lrow, i As Long

strCancel = "N"
strWorkbookNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (FileFilter:=strFilt, _
    FilterIndex:=intFilterIndex, _
    Title:=strDialogueFileTitle, _
    MultiSelect:=True) 'add this line which will let you select all the files
'your variable now contains array of filenames
fileArraySize = UBound(strWorkbookNameAndPath, 1) 'count how many files
'loop and open the files
For i = 1 To fileArraySize
    'open the file
    Set wkbImportedWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(strWorkbookNameAndPath(i))
    Set wksImportedWorksheet = wkbImportedWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets1")
    'copy all contents and paste on masterfile
    With wksImportedWorksheet
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngImportCopyRange = .Range("A1:A" & lrow).EntireRow
        rngImportCopyRange.Copy
        wksMasterWorksheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    'close the source file
    wkbImportedWorkbook.Close
    Set wkbImportedWorkbook = Nothing
    Set wksImportedWorksheet = Nothing
Next i
Else
    MsgBox "An Open Error Occurred Importing Your File Selection"
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

Exit Sub
errhandler:

MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred!" & vbNewLine & _
    "Error No.: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & _
    "Description: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error Notification"

End Sub
```

I removed the `Private Sub` and embedded the loading of file in the main code.
But you can always extract that part and make it a `Private Sub` if you're going to use it in other `Subs`.
I've tested this and it works fine.
If there are parts of the code that you do not understand, just comment it out.

Comment: thanks for the code, it works perfectly well as i've asked but another problem is occuring in my program, you see, i was trying to open multiple of workbooks into my excel sheet and compile them altogether into one sheet(the master workbook), the previous code does it well but as far as it goes, the previous code can only load one workbook at a time into the master sheet. So the problem now is, when i run the new code, it opens the 2nd workbook into a new excel instead of the master one.

Comment: of course. :) it will only open the files. you need to add more code inside the `For Loop` to take care of the consolidation. try something, and if you get stuck somewhere, just update your question and help is on the way.

Comment: i have upload the rest of the codes here, where should i include the loop??